# Как вызвать окно выбора геопозиции в telegram?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

В мобильной версии телеграмма если нажать на скрепку и выбрать пункт "Геопозиция", то можно выбрать на карте любой адрес и отправить данные нажатием кнопки "Отправить геопозицию".

Как можно вызвать этот функционал с помощью бота?
sendLocation и sendVenue отправляют карту с уже заданными широтой и долготой. Как сделать чтобы пользователь сам мог выбрать нужный адрес?

Я использую библиотеку php-telegram-bot

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, через API нельзя попросить пользователя указать любое место на карте средствами самого телеграма. Можно запросить только текущее местоположение с помощью keyboardButonn - request_location